# AngularJS http eventHandlers vs uploadEventHandlers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, event-handling

I am trying to track progress on post request and I only get progress from **uploadEventHandlers**, but not from **eventHandlers** (see code below). The progress that I get from **uploadEventHandlers** contains transferred length and total length which is great. However I have these questions:

1. What is **eventHandlers** used for?
2. Let's say, after all data is uploaded, server has to perform time
   consuming operations on that data (network transfer, files
   uncompress) before returning HTTP response. Is there any way the
   server can indicate to the client about the progress (besides
   logging DB and polling by the client)?

---

```
$http({
    url: baseUrlService.baseURL + 'importtifile',
    method: 'POST',
    data: myData

    eventHandlers: {
        progress: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },

    uploadEventHandlers: {
        progress: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}).then(
...
```

Answer (score 4):

1. eventHandler is used to attach and handle other events. Use only uploadEventHandlers to track upload file progress.
2. You can use eventHandlers --> readystatechange,  to track the state of the connection. So, when readyState equals 4, you know the server has closed the connection.

Note: You can inform user that server will perform additional work after the upload files reaches 100%.

This is your modified code:

```html
$http({
    url: baseUrlService.baseURL + 'importtifile',
    method: 'POST',
    data: myData

    eventHandlers: {
        readystatechange: function(event) {
                        if(event.currentTarget.readyState === 4) {
                            console.log("readyState=4: Server has finished extra work!");
                        }
                    }
    },

    uploadEventHandlers: {
        progress: function(e) {
             if (e.lengthComputable) {
                progress = Math.round(e.loaded * 100 / e.total);
                console.log("progress: " + progress + "%");
                if (e.loaded == e.total) {
                  console.log("File upload finished!");
                  console.log("Server will perform extra work now...");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).then(
...
```